# Defining attributes of a class in Python

Tags: python

How should I define the attributes of a class?

```
class Example:

   def __init__(self,n,m):
     self.n=n
     self.m=m
```

or in this way:

```
class Example:
  m=0
  n=0

  def __init__(self,n,m):
    self.n=n
    self.m=m
```

If I define an attribute outside the constructor, is it a static variable?

Comment: It depends - do you want them to be *class attributes* (shared by all instances) or *instance attributes* (individual to each instance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing instance variables and variables of the class itself (you could call them static if you are coming from java). Have a look at this demo (note that `__init__` needs two underscores).

```
class Example:
    m=0
    n=0

    def __init__(self,n,m):
        self.n=n
        self.m=m

e = Example(1,2)
print(e.m) # 2
print(e.n) # 1
print(Example.m) # 0
print(Example.n) # 0
```

In your second code, `Example` has the class variables `m` and `n`, and each instance of an `Example` object will have instance members `self.m` and `self.n`.

Comment: yes I am coming from Java... so m and n are like class variables (static variable) in Java, and self.n and self.m are object variables... and I do not need to define them outside the constructor..

Comment: @Shiran yes, if you don't want the `Example` class itself (as opposed to instances of that class) have the attributes `n` and `m` there's no need for the first two lines after `class Example`.

Answer (score 3):

This way:

```
class Example:

  def __init__(self,n,m):
    self.n=n
    self.m=m
```

Double score the `init`, like this: `__init__`, not like this `_init_`!

`m=0` and `n=0` are class attributes, and don't have anything with `self.n` and `self.m`, which are instance variables.